# suggests or suggested?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

I'd like to know the difference in these two sentences:

1. He said the cause is not known, but evidence at the scene **suggested** foul play.
2. He said the cause is not known, but evidence at the scene **suggests** foul play.

Is there any difference in nuance and meaning?

Not really sure what the issue is and the need for the edit. I completely understand the difference in past and present tense. The issue arises from how it is used and if there is a difference in meaning. The answer I marked correct answered this for me clearly.

Comment: Welcome! Please use the "Edit" link under the question to explain a bit more. One uses the past tense, the other present. If you don't understand the difference that they bring, maybe read up on them and ask on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange about the difference. If you have concerns about reported speech or about mixing tenses, please edit to make your concerns clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I've added *that*'s to avoid the ambiguity.]

- (2) *He said that the cause is not known, but that evidence at the scene suggests foul play.*

This is fine; the incident is recent (at the time it is here being reported), and the cause remains unknown and the suggestion of foul play has not been disproved.

..........

- (1) *He said that the cause is not known, but that evidence at the scene suggested foul play.*

This is somewhat problematic. The cause remains unknown at the time the speaker (not 'he') makes the statement, fine ... but the switch here to 'suggested' can reasonably be taken to mean that the 'evidence of foul play' has now been reinterpreted  (if this is not the case, inconsistency of tenses is used). And one would expect a clearer explanation were this to be the case.

One could well hear this in real life though; it can be claimed that it's justified where the cause remains unknown while the evidence has since been washed away by a heavy storm, say.

Comment: It wouldn't even take an elaborate storm scenario; as long as the speaker was referencing a past visit to the scene, there's every reason for his report to be in the past tense but the lack of knowledge to be present.

Comment: That would be infelicitous without a caveat mentioning the reason for the tense switch.